# Oracle query performance degrades when inserting many rows in a single transaction

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

In a single transaction I am inserting may rows into a table, before inserting the row I perform a query to see if there is already a row with the key I am about to insert.

What I see is that the query to check the key exists gets very slow within my transaction, but from another transaction it is fast, and in the next transaction it is fast.

I cant break this work down into smaller transactions as the request I am processing needs to be in a single transaction.

Is there anything I can do to make the select query in this transaction fast?

Comment: Why do you check if the row already exists? Create a unique constraint (or index) and simply deal with the error.

Comment: Yes, a_horse_with_no_name is right. Why replicate the built-in functionality which is gozillion times more efficient!

Comment: Use `merge` to avoid inserting duplicates.

Comment: You can create unique constraint or index /primary key (as  @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned).
Also, please try to find what take the time - your selects, or your inserts. May be you should add indexes for fields your are selecting by

Comment: I am using Hibernate to perform the queries, as far as I am aware once you get a Database exception in Hibernate you are obliged to roll the transaction back.

Comment: evgenyl It is the select that takes the time.

Comment: The "beauty" of DBMS obfuscators....

Comment: I'd bet the 2nd..nth queries are pulling blocks from cache (the 1st is doing the physical i/o).  Does your company employ Oracle devs?  Perhaps they can batch this properly in the db

Comment: @Greg - Not enough info to help you. Is problem with query that checks row exists or insert part? How do you check the row exists? If problems with Inserts then did you try merge, conditional insert, adding Append hint etc... Not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

So, please add constraint / primary key. This will allow you to remove all your selects.
May be consider to use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) as @ Egor_Skriptunoff recommended.

OR Add indexes for columns you are selected by.

Comment: I have indexes on the columns I am selecting by. I cant wait for the constraint violation exception as I am using hibernate and once there is a DB error I must roll the transaction back and start again.

Comment: I dont think I can use merge as Hibernate is generating the SQL.

Comment: I am not familiar with Hibernet, but can you run your transaction in  Store Procedure? If so, you'll be able to use merge, as well as handle constraint violation in your way. This can help with Store Procedures: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

if inserting millions of thousand of records first thing is do incremental commits as you are likely hitting temp space fragmentation or limits which result in slowdowns. that can be done in a begin end block 
also,  this allows you to add index via

```
create index b indexName on table_name(col1, col2, col3);
```

merge is faster as previous answer states.
alternatively add all ignoring duplicates then remove duplicates 
this can be done via
for example

```
begin
    insert into table_name select * from table_name; [ if pulling from another table]or[use values and column maps]
    delete from table_name A where rowid >(select min(rowid) from table_name B where A.key_value=B.key_value);
end
```

if in a procedure this would also require 
both query and delete can be in begin end block and execute immediate(' you ddl statement here';');